# how to split string by template

Tags: javascript

I have a long string of messages, and I have to split it by the template: `[DD/MM/YYYY, HH:MM:SS]`.
as you can understand the `[]` are constant and the date-time is different.

How can I do that?

Comment: what do you mean by split? Please add an example of the output you want.

Comment: please paste sample input and show us what have you tried ?

Comment: @vesii I think they mean trim/strip.

Comment: please add some data and the wanted result.

Comment: `.split(/\[\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d, \d\d:\d\d:\d\d\]/)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert the given tempalte into a regular expression ans split with this pattern and keep this pattern in the result set.

```js
const
    text = '[20/09/2020, 15:31:23] foo\n[21/09/2020, 15:31:23] bar\n[22/09/2020, 15:31:23] baz',
    result = text.split(/(\[\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}, \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\])/);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression like `/^\[(.+)\]$/` to strip the square-brackets.

```
/       BEGIN EXPRESSION
  ^     START OF LINE
  \[    CHAR LITERAL '['
  (.+)  GROUP 1: ANYTHING IN-BETWEEN
  \]    CHAR LITERAL ']'
  $     END OF LINE
/       END EXPRESSION
```

```js
const str = '[DD/MM/YYYY, HH:MM:SS]'; // Where content is a real timestamp

console.log(str.replace(/^\[(.+)\]$/, '$1')); // DD/MM/YYYY, HH:MM:SS
```